# Android studio Emulator doesn't run my first activity it gives an Installation ERROR with white screen who never responds

Tags: android, android-studio

I´m a beginner at Android development and just started using  Android Studio.  When  I try to run one of the sample programs (First activity which says "Hello world!") using the emulator Nexus 5x API 25. I have as android version 2.3 as : classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0' and as first android features i have this two features :
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig { ...

I get this error message:

Installation failed with message null. 
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.
WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!.

With a white screen, and android never starts on this emulator
I tried to uses diffrent emulators but it gives the same error or says : ERROR installing APKs

Had someone alreédy the same ERROR? , how can i fixe this ? ...,Thanks for advance for any help :)

Comment: please read these: [ask] & [mcve] & [help/on-topic], to increase your chance of getting answers to your questions!

Answer (score 0):

Just after seeing this error, **go to your emulator** which probably is running, **then just go to the apps menu, find your installed app** which will have the default android logo **and uninstall it**. Then close the emulator and try running it again!

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Does the emulator run at all?

**Try these (test after you try each one):**

1. Build -> Clean Project
2. Build -> Rebuild Project
3. Restart Android Studio and emulator
4. If the emulator runs then you could try removing the app

*Try to be a little more clear with your asking if you can. I hope you solve it!*

Cheers.